# Where can I get PHP to install on windows server (x64)

Tags: php, 64-bit, windows-server

I'm trying to find PHP to install on a windows server machine (x64), but don't seem to find it on http://windows.php.net/download.

A ftp link would be helpfull thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't natively support 64 bit Windows yet... depending on which web server you're installing with you'll want 5.3:

- Apache - VC6
- IIS - VC9

Note: There are unofficial PHP x64 versions out there for Windows - but who can recommend that ;)

Comment: Not my choice. I have to use IIS.

Will it work properly on Windows Server x64?

Comment: I meant using the x86 versions.

Comment: Lots of people out there to say it works fine.  PHP 32 bit is faster than 64 but the big issue is not all the underlying libraries are 64 bit compatible yet/rewritten.  If you want an x64 version, there are independent developers keeping them going, but you install at your own risk, not recommended for production, don't have the latest security patches or all PHP library functionality available.

Answer (score 0):

I am running PHP5.3 VC6 Thread Safe from php.net (using it with Apache) on Windows Foundation Server 2008. No problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

There's only officious support for PHP x64.

You can compile it yourself. You'll need to follow [these instructions](http://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild) and download the [dependencies](http://pecl2.php.net/downloads/php-windows-builds/php-libs/VC9/x64/).

There are also [pre-compiled binaries](http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=415).